# Spotify video background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If you go to spotify.com for the first time it plays a cool video and has some different stuff overlayed on it. I think this is a great and unique way to engage people on a website and would like to replicate that kind of functionality.

It looks like the video resizes beautifully. They have quite a few scripts running on the page and I wanted to know the bare bones of what's necessary to produce that same kind of result. I am familiar with JQuery and such, but not 100% sure how to make the video resize with the screen and produce this result.

If someone could give me the an example of what the minimum is necessary to produce this, that would be great. Also, what would be the best way to handle this for mobile devices?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend simply taking a look at [BigVideo.js](http://dfcb.github.com/BigVideo.js/). It seems very functional

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this pretty easily with some basic CSS

```
<video autoplay loop="loop" preload="auto" src="video.webm"></video>

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```